# Finding the equation of an ellipse on a tilted plane

Tags: geometry

So if I rotated an ellipse that was originally on the $xy$ plane around its minor axis, so that it is now on a tilted plane that intersects the $xy$ plane at the ellipse’s minor axis, how would I find the equation of the rotated ellipse?

Comment: What sort of equation are you looking for? Curves in 3d can’t be represented by a single implicit Cartesian equation. On the other hand, transforming a parametric equation of the ellipse is straightforward.

Comment: Let’s try the parametric version, please.

Comment: Or could I also represent it as a solution set of a plane intersecting a cone?